# SVG image in UIWebview is not scaling properly

Tags: c#, xamarin, svg, xamarin.ios

SVG image in the Html page is scaling properly in the internet explorers but if it implemented in the UIwebviw it is not scaling properly. I have attached the runnable sample with the issue.

To view the first click the zoom in button in the application and then reduce the zoom using the zoom out button to a minimum and then repeat the same .you will see the web content is cropped on the sides.

[DOWNLOAD Sample here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FD85owkU9QiCFQ9_cgaPXcyoOmDLKML8)

[image: Black color is the SVG content yellow color is UIWebview]

Comment: Write the SVG image in the Html page and load the html page in UIWebview maybe a solution. UIWebView seems can't scale SVG image correctly.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT image is viewed correctly for the first time and but it seems to cropped when size is increased continuously and decreased . I don't know whether it is the issue of Webview or SVG image in HTML?

Comment: I feel the problem happens when you change the frame of webView. Even I set webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;, it won't work.

Comment: A lot of users have been getting rejection notices for using UIWebView that has been deprecated for several years https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview . Consider using WKWebView instead, it's an easy transition

Comment: wkwebview is also having the same issue.